# Set property in Win32_Volume

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to figure out how to set "IndexingEnabled" property value for a disk (disk indexing is enabled/disabled). From the documentation it follows that this property can be read/write.

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher Win32_Volume =
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select IndexingEnabled from Win32_Volume where DriveLetter = 'C:'"))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject volume in Win32_Volume.Get())
    {
        volume.SetPropertyValue("IndexingEnabled", true); // true or false
    }
}
```

or

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("Select IndexingEnabled from Win32_Volume where DriveLetter='C:'");
scope.Connect();

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
    foreach (ManagementBaseObject drive in searcher.Get())
    {
        drive.SetPropertyValue("IndexingEnabled", true);
    }
}
```

An error is not generated, but the value of the property does not change. Administrator rights are active. What am I doing wrong? thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetPropertyValue` only updates the wrapper object. The changes are not committed (and do not become effective) until [`Put`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject.put?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Management_ManagementObject_Put) is called, for example `volume.Put();`.